# My code is populating the top/heading row, but it shouldn't be

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which has set the range not to include the top row in excel when printing an error message. However it seems like there is a mistake in my code as when I run it, it prints my error message in `row 1`.

```
Sub Misc_box8()

  Dim cell As Range
  Dim lastRow As Long
  lastRow = Worksheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

  For Each cell In Worksheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Range("N2:" & "N" & lastRow)
    If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
        cell.Offset(0, -13).Value = cell.Offset(0, -13).Value & ", Box 8 is not a number"
    End If
   Next

End Sub
```

For the error message not to show up in `row 1`. But to show up if applicable in `row2` to `last row` Thanks.

Comment: The error is not in your posted code.  Something else is writing into row #1.

Comment: If the value of `lastRow` is `1`, then `cell` will be in the `N1:N2` range. Add `Debug.Print lastRow` before the `For Each` loop, then put a breakpoint (F9) on the `For Each` statement, and when the breakpoint is hit, bring up the *immediate* pane (Ctrl+G). What's the value of `lastRow`?

Comment: Thanks for the inx, the value comes up as 1

Comment: How should I proceed?

Comment: Look at the `1099-Misc_Form_Template` sheet and confirm column `N` isn't the best place to get the "last row" from, then assess the data on that sheet and get the "last row" off a column that contains data for every single row.

Comment: Or, `If lastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Thanks, solved by changing the row from N to B which is more applicable to getting the lastrow from :)